# How to use JavaScriptCore get a Nsstring from js function

Tags: javascript, ios, javascriptcore

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirectNative() {
        bluewhale:funTo("FAIL");
    }
</script>
```

OC code :

```
self.context[@"redirectNative"]=
    ^(NSString *str)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"msg from js" message:str delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    };
```

this Methond don't get the "FAIL"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to use your `redirectNative` Objective-C function from JavaScript, you would simply call it.  I'm not sure what all this `bluewhale:FunTo()` business is all about.  Just call `redirectNative("FAIL")` from JavaScript and it should do what you want, given the Objective-C snippet you provided.